# NDSolve for complex BVPs and FindRoot

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex

NDSolve works for complex valued ODE initial value problems (IVP). However, for a simple boundary value problem (BVP) with complex coefficients it fails:

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + (1 + I) Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == 1, x[10] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

*FindRoot::trcx: The search has encountered a complex value and the trust region step control method is only implemented for real values.*

The difficulty seems to be that the internal call to FindRoot to solve the shooting method matching is trying a method (trust region step control) that is not implemented for complex numbers.

I would like to get around this by somehow telling FindRoot to use line search instead. Since there does not appear to be a way to pass this through the NDSolve options to FindRoot, I tried globally resetting the default FindRoot options:

```
SetOptions[FindRoot, Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}]
```

However, a subsequent call to NDSolve returned the same error as before, i.e., a complaint about trust region step control. So it didn't use linear search!

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to pass options through NDSolve to FindRoot?
2. Why doesn't the call to SetOptions work?
3. Is there another way to get Mathematica to solve a complex BVP? (Yes, I know I can always split the equation into real and imaginary parts, but this is rather inconvenient for the much more complicated problems I'm actually trying to solve. Besides, as a matter of principle, since Mathematica generally handles complex variables seamlessly, it seems there should be a more direct way to do this.)

Comment: Hi! You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tutorial [Numerical Solution of Boundary Value Problems (BVP)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html) has a description of the suboptions to the `"Shooting"` method.  The option you want is `"ImplicitSolver"`:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x''[t] + (1 + I) Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
    x[10] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}];

Plot[ReIm@x[t] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update:*
The reason `SetOptions` does not work is that `NDSolve` overrides the options of `FindRoot`, which I think may be inferred from the output of the following:

```
Trace[
 NDSolve[{x''[t] + (1 + I) Sin[x[t]] == 0, x[0] == 1, x[10] == 0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 10}],
 _FindRoot,
 TraceInternal -> True]
(* {{{...some output omitted...
  {FindRoot[NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`nf$337017, 
   SetPrecision[{{NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`start$337017}}, 
    NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`prec$337017], 
   "AccuracyGoal" -> NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`ag$337017, 
   "PrecisionGoal" -> NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`pg$337017, 
   "MaxIterations" -> NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`maxit$337017, 
   "Method" -> NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`frmethod$337017, 
   "WorkingPrecision" -> NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`prec$337017]},...}}}
*)
```

You can add the option `TraceAbove -> True` if you really want to track it down.  You'll see a line like

```
If[NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`frmethod$337017 === Automatic, 
 NDSolve`Shooting`ShootingDump`frmethod$337017 = {"Newton", 
   "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}]
```