# Error when solving 't Hooft-Polyakov radial equations using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying to solve 2 coupled nonlinear ODEs using NDSolve, but the solution fails when the parameter $\lambda$ increases. The equations are
$$r^2 a''(r)= a(r) [a(r)-1] [a(r)-2]- r^2 [1-a(r)] h(r)^2,$$
$$\left(r^2 h'(r)\right)'= 2 [1-a(r)]^2 h(r)+ \lambda\,r^2 [h(r)^2-1]\, h(r).$$
And the boundary conditions are
$$a(0)=h(0)=0,$$
$$a(\infty)= h(\infty)=1.$$
I've tried to solve it in the following way:

```
\[Lambda] = 0.1; 
r1 = 10^(-6); r2 = 9.5; 
eqn = {r^2*D[D[a[r], r], r] == a[r]*(a[r] - 1)*(a[r] - 2) - r^2*h[r]^2*(1 - a[r]), 
    D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 2*h[r]*(1 - a[r])^2 + \[Lambda]*r^2*(h[r]^2 - 1)*h[r]}; 
bc = {a[r1] == 0, a[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, h[r2] == 1}; 
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc} /. {a -> (#1^2*g[#1] & ), h -> (#1*j[#1] & )}, {g, j}, {r, r1, r2}, 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]; 
Plot[{1, 1 - r^2*sol[[1]][r], r*sol[[2]][r]}, {r, r1, r2}]
```

And, indeed, I get a solution.

[image]

This works for $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=0.1$. However, I would like to get the solution for a larger range of $\lambda$, for example $\lambda=1$. When I try to use the code above and set $\lambda=1$ Mathematica gives me the following

```
NDSolveValue: At r == 1.2395178650126792`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

NDSolveValue: The scaled boundary value residual error of 62.94578090521123` indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found.
```

As a consequence, the plot does not correspond to a solution.

So, my question is: How can I get a solution to these equations when $\lambda=1$, for example? Is it possible to calculate for larger values?

Besides that, how can I use the results of NDSolve in an integral of the form

$$E=4\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}dr\,\left[(a')^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2(a-2)^2}{r^2}+ \frac{1}{2}r^2(h')^2 + h^2(a-1)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4}r^2(h^2-1)^2 \right]?$$

I know this problem has a solution, because the equations are those of the 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole and the last integral is its mass as a function of $\lambda$. But, I'm new in Mathematica and I don't know how to correctly reproduce the solutions which are available at textbooks.

Any hint is valuable to me!

Thanks in advance.

***Update:***Just to make it clear, I would like to stress that I know this problem has been solved. The plots of the solution are available at textbooks on topological solitons, such as [Manton, Sutcliffe] and [Shnir]. What I'm trying to say is that I would like to understand how to obtain this solution in Mathematica. The question marked as a possible duplicate is the solution of the Abelian string (also ANO vortex), which is different. One can see this when looking, for example, into the kinetic part given in those terms with derivatives. Could you, please, give some hints on how I should improve my code?

Comment: The short answer is that it seems to be very sensitive to initial conditions.  You should look up the `"Shooting"` method and adjust `"StartingInitialConditions"`.  You can use a nearby solution for them. A lambda that works may be increased a little and a new solution produced. Little by little you might be able to push lambda up to `1`.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that this question is morally a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33538/numerical-solution-of-coupled-odes-with-boundary-conditions).  This set of differential equations was also studied in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0412057).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numerical solution of coupled ODEs with boundary conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33538/numerical-solution-of-coupled-odes-with-boundary-conditions)

Comment: Dear @QuantumDot, I know this paper, but there they do not explicitly show how the calculation was done and, besides that, I was trying to reproduce it in Mathematica. This monopole solution is well-known, but books on topological solitons do not discuss in detail **how** it is done. I edited the end of my question, if you can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @Michael. As I mentioned in the question, I'm new in Mathematica (just a few days using) and I didn't know about "Shooting" in Wolfram Language. What I have seen was your answer to the question [91854] (mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/…), but I couldn't generalize the method for my 2 coupled equations. So, about my question: could you, please, just explain me a little more on pushing lambda up?

Comment: Let's say you have a solution for a given lambda with `firstsol = First@NDSolve[..]`. Then increase lambda a little and try again with `nextsol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc} /. {a -> (#1^2*g[#1] &), h -> (#1*j[#1] &)}, {g, j}, {r, r1, r2}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {{g[r1], g'[r1], j[r1], j'[r1]} == ({g[r1], g'[r1], j[r1], j'[r1]} /. firstsol)}}]`. If that works, let `firstsol = nextsol` and repeat. You can put it in a loop. (I tried but it doesn't get very far.  One might need very small increases in lambda. I don't have time to investigate at the moment.)

Comment: Interesting example. You say that you are happy with the solution for `\lambda = 0.1`, but if I insert `r->0` into the solution the boundary conditions are not satisfied. Am I missing something?

Comment: After your commentary, I've tried to implement it @Michael, but I couldn't get a solution. Maybe I increasead \lambda too much in a step.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean @user21. Could you explain again?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it seems that the final solution does not satisfy the boundary conditions. Or am I making a mistake her?

Comment: Well @user21, I think the solution is satisfying the boundary conditions. But when plotting we use h[r] e 1-a[r], so this may lead to confusion since the BCs seem to be inverted, but they are not. However, I'm not sure if this is what you meant :)

Comment: I have tried to clarify a bit what strikes me as odd. Please see the 'answer' below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once again, compared to `"Shooting"` method that is the default and currently the only available method for solving nonlinear boundary value problem (BVP) inside `NDSolve`, finite difference method (FDM) seems to be a better choice for solving this problem. I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equations.

```
r1 = 10^(-6); r2 = 9.5`8;
eqn = {r^2*D[D[a[r], r], r] == a[r]*(a[r] - 1)*(a[r] - 2) - r^2*h[r]^2*(1 - a[r]), 
   D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 2*h[r]*(1 - a[r])^2 + λ*r^2*(h[r]^2 - 1)*h[r]};
bc = {a[r1] == 0, a[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, h[r2] == 1};
{neweqn, newbc} = {eqn, bc} /. {a -> (#1^2*g[#1] &), h -> (#1*j[#1] &)};
difforder = 4;
domain = {r1, r2};
points = 50;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{g, j}[r], grid, difforder];
delete = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = delete /@ ptoafunc@neweqn;
aebc = ptoafunc@newbc;

initialfunc[g][r_] = 1/2;
initialfunc[j][r_] = 1/2;

sollst = Partition[
   Block[{λ = 1}, 
     FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, 
      Flatten[Table[{var[index], initialfunc[var][index]}, {var, {g, j}}, {index, grid}],
        1]]][[All, -1]], points];

{solg, solj} = ListInterpolation[#, domain] & /@ sollst;

Plot[{1, 1 - r^2*solg[r], r*solj[r]} // Evaluate, {r, r1, r2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As one can see, the initial guesses used here i.e. `initialfunc[g][r]` and `initialfunc[j][r]` are rather rough, but we still obtain the desired result.

As to the integral, I think the straightforward solution isn't bad:

```
Ε = 
 With[{a = r^2*solg[r], h = r*solj[r], λ = 1}, 
  4 Pi NIntegrate[
    D[a, r]^2 + 1/2 a^2 (a - 2)^2/r^2 D[h, r]^2 + 
     h^2 (a - 1)^2 + λ/4 r^2 (h^2 - 1)^2, {r, r1, r2}]]
(* 9.74871 *)
```

You may adjust `points` etc. to make the result preciser.

---

## Update

It turns out that

1. the transformation $a(r)=r^2 g(r)$ and $h(r)=r j(r)$
2. approximating $r_1=0$ with $r_1=10^{-6}$

is **not** necessary:

```
r1 = 0; r2 = 95/10;
eqn = {r^2*D[D[a[r], r], r] == a[r]*(a[r] - 1)*(a[r] - 2) - r^2*h[r]^2*(1 - a[r]), 
   D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 2*h[r]*(1 - a[r])^2 + λ*r^2*(h[r]^2 - 1)*h[r]};
bc = {a[r1] == 0, a[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, h[r2] == 1};
{neweqn, newbc} = {eqn, bc};
difforder = 4;
domain = {r1, r2};
points = 50;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

(*Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,please find it in the link above.*)


ptoafunc = pdetoae[{a, h}[r], grid, difforder];
delete = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = delete /@ ptoafunc@neweqn;
aebc = ptoafunc@newbc;
initialfunc[a][r_] = 1/2;
initialfunc[h][r_] = 1/2;
sollst = Partition[
   Block[{λ = 1}, 
     FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, 
      Flatten[Table[{var[index], initialfunc[var][index]}, {var, {a, h}}, {index, grid}],
        1]]][[All, -1]], points];
{sola, solh} = ListInterpolation[#, domain] & /@ sollst;

Plot[{1, 1 - sola[r], solh[r]} // Evaluate, {r, r1, r2}]
```

The result is the same so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: Thank you very much @xzczd! I will try to understand it, since it is a sophisticated code for me.

Comment: Have a look at the comment I posted. Do you perhaps have an opinion on that?

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but a remark about the boundary conditions.

Let's look at the equation:

```
r1 = 10^(-6);
r2 = 95/10;
lambda = 1/10;
eqn = {r^2*D[D[a[r], r], r] == 
    a[r]*(a[r] - 1)*(a[r] - 2) - r^2*h[r]^2*(1 - a[r]), 
   D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 
    2*h[r]*(1 - a[r])^2 + \[Lambda]*r^2*(h[r]^2 - 1)*h[r]};
bc = {a[r1] == 0, a[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, h[r2] == 1};
{teqn, tbc} = {eqn, bc} /. {a -> (#1^2*g[#1] &), h -> (#1*j[#1] &)};
teqn /. {g -> u, j -> v} // Expand;
{gsol, jsol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{teqn, tbc} /. \[Lambda] -> lambda, {g, j}, {r, r1, 
    r2}, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
```

If we look at the plot:

```
Plot[{gsol[r], jsol[r]}, {r, r1, r2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 0.15}, All}]
```

[image]

We note a jump at the left hand side. The solver has trouble satisfying this BC (and the solver xzczd wrote has a similar problem).

The actual values:

```
{gsol[r] - 0, jsol[r] - 0} /. r -> r1
{gsol[r] - 1/90.25, jsol[r] - 1/9.5} /. r -> r2

{0.00147074, 1.38778*10^-16}
{-1.23805*10^-10, 2.58372*10^-11}
```

Do not quite match the requested bc at `r1` for `gsol`. If one looks at:

```
{{r^2 gsol[r] - 0, r jsol[r] - 0} /. 
  r -> r1, {r^2 gsol[r] - 1, r jsol[r] - 1} /. r -> r2}

{{1.47074*10^-15, 1.38778*10^-22}, {-1.11734*10^-8, 2.45454*10^-10}}
```

Things look better. But the issue of the kink remains.

If you were, just for fun (this is not the right thing to do), to replace the bcs in the following way:

```
{gsol2, jsol2} = 
  NDSolveValue[{teqn, {g[1/1000000] == gsol[0.001], 
      90.25` g[9.5`] == 1, j[1/1000000] == jsol[0.001], 
      9.5` j[9.5`] == 1}} /. \[Lambda] -> lambda, {g, j}, {r, r1, r2},
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
```

You will note that the convergence is much quicker then with the above BCs. Where did you find these BCs. Are sure they make sense and are correct?

Comment: I'm afraid you've made a mistake on checking, the correct one should be `{{r^2 gsol[r] - 0, r jsol[r] - 0} /. r -> r1,
{r^2 gsol[r] - 1, r jsol[r] - 1} /. r -> r2}` :)

Comment: @xzczd thanks. Even if one takes `r^2 gsol[r]` the kink per se remains and indicates trouble that that boundary.

Comment: I think the kink is reasonable, because `r1 = 10^(-6)` is probably an approximation of `r1 = 0`. For `r1 = 0`, `a[0]` and `j[0]` can be non-zero.

Comment: @xzczd, but the problem statement is that the bc `a(0)=0`. Too me this looks odd.

Comment: Oops, actually I meant `g[0]` and `j[0]`.

Comment: The transformation made by OP turns out to be unnecessary. See my update for more details.

Comment: @xzczd and that actually does give a better solution - no kink.

Comment: @xzczd, I'm sorry I haven't seen your answers before. It happens that my SE app didn't notify me :)

Comment: Dear xzczd and @user21... Regarding the questions, thank you both of you!!! It is really nice to know that the transformation wasn't necessary. Do you guys know if there is a simple way to extend r2 to larger values? Finally, I should mention that this boundary conditions arise in order for the topological monopole solution to be non-singular at the origin and to have finite energy. If you ask Mathematica to series expand the equations to first order (around r=0), you will see that a[0]=0 is necessary to get rid of a singularity.

Comment: @MLPhysics The FDM approach seems to be quite stable, my code manages to find the correct answer even with `r2 = 20` for `λ = 1`. If you want to make `r2` even larger, you probably need a better initial guess. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161806/1871) is an example.

Comment: @xzczd I understand what you mean... After trying to solve a problem similar to this one in Mathematica, I did it in MATLAB using the bvp4c solver, which aims to solve BVPs. There, I made a better initial guess and could solve the equations to r2=50 :) However, when calculating the integral E, I needed to use trapezoidal integration and I'm not sure which one is the best: NIntegrate in Mathematica or trapz in MATLAB.   Are you, by any chance, a MATLAB user too? Do you know if there are other ways of integrating data which comes from differential equations?

Comment: Oh, and I'm sorry to bother you, I know this website is not "MATLAB SE"!

Comment: @MLPhysics Well, I know little about MATLAB. As to integration, trapezoidal integration is a relatively primitive integration method, but it's not necessarily a worse method for your integrand, because the accuracy is also limited by the ODE solver. I'm afraid the only way for determining which one is more suitable is, try them out.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! And I'm also grateful for your past answers.