# NDSolve Convergence Issue for Coupled Field Problems

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, modeling, boundary-conditions

I have tried to use NDSolve to solve a coupled field Eqs (see the attached Codes). The MMA solver seems to failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations

```
ClearAll[y, x, t];
L = 10;
ode1 = y''[t] == 0;
ic11 = y[0] == 0;
ic12 = x[L]^2*y'[L] == 100;
ode2 = -1 + x[t] + x[t]*(y'[t]^2 + y''[t]^2) - 2 x''[t] == 0;
ic21 = x'[0] == 0;
ic22 = x'[L] == 0;
NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic11, ic12, ic21, ic22}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

How can I remove the error warning in MMA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Symbolic Solution**

This ODE system can be solved symbolically as follows.

```
sy = (DSolve[{ode1, ic11}, y, t] // Flatten) /. C[2] -> c
(* {y -> Function[{t}, t c]} *)
sx = DSolve[{ode2 /. sy, ic21, ic22}, x, t] // Flatten
(* {x -> Function[{t}, 1/(1 + c^2)]} *)
sc = Solve[ic12 /. sx /. sy, c] // N // Flatten
(* {c -> -0.0353443 - 1.03537 I, c -> -0.0353443 + 1.03537 I, 
    c -> 0.0353443 - 0.964633 I, c -> 0.0353443 + 0.964633 I} *)
1/(1 + #^2) & /@ (sc // Values)
(* {-6.82769 - 7.06475 I, -6.82769 + 7.06475 I, 
     7.32769 + 7.06412 I,  7.32769 - 7.06412 I} *)
```

The fact that the solution is complex is the source of the `FindRoot` error.

**Numerical Solution**

If a numerical solution is desired, perhaps as a prototype for a more complicated system of ODEs, the following code can be used.

```
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ic11, ic12, ic21, ic22}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -7 - 7 I, y'[0] == -I}}];
```

The "Shooting" `Method` is needed, because this is a boundary value problem, and the "ImplicitSolver" option is needed, because the solution is complex.  (The latter is illustrated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124460/1063).)  Note that the "StartingInitialConditions" guess does not need to be very accurate but it does need to be complex.  Here are plots of the solution.

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@First[sn], {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, x}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Last[sn], {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Numerical solutions corresponding to the other values of `c`, above, are obtained from other choices of "StartingInitialConditions":

```
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 7 - 7 I, y'[0] == I}
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 7 + 7 I, y'[0] == -I}
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -7 + 7 I, y'[0] == I}
```

**Addendum: Oscillatory Solutions**

The solution above, although accurate, is incomplete in that `DSolve` as used omitted oscillatory eigenfunction-like solutions.  They can be derived as follows:

```
ode2x = ode2 /. sy /. c^2 -> csq
Collect[DSolveValue[{% /. sy, ic21}, x[t], t, Assumptions -> csq < -1], 
    C[1], FullSimplify] // Flatten
(* -1 + x[t] + csq x[t] - 2 (x''[t] == 0 *)
(* 1/(1 + csq) + 2 C[1] Cos[(Sqrt[-1 - csq] t)/Sqrt[2]] *)
```

Visibly, `ic22` is satisfied for `n Pi/L == Sqrt[-1 - csq]/Sqrt[2]`, providing an expression for`c^2` and in turn simplifying x[t].

```
scsq = Solve[n Pi/L == Sqrt[-1 - csq]/Sqrt[2], csq] // Flatten
(* {csq -> 1/50 (-50 - n^2 π^2)} *)
sn = Simplify[%% /. scsq, n > 0]
(* -(50/(n^2 π^2)) + 2 C[1] Cos[(n π t)/10] *)
```

Finally, apply `ic12` to evaluate `C[1]`

```
ic12x = ic12 /. sy
Simplify[ic12x /. x[10] -> (sn /. t -> L), n ∈ Integers];
Simplify[((#^2 & /@ %) /. c[10]^2 -> csq) /. scsq /. C[1] -> coef] /. 
    c^2 -> csq /. scsq
(* c x[10]^2 == 100 *)
(* 1/50 (-50 - n^2 π^2) (50/(n^2 π^2) - 2 (-1)^n C[1])^4 == 10000 *)
```

From this last equation, `C[1]` and in turn the final expression for `x[t]` are obtained, although the results are a bit long to reproduce here.

```
sc1 = (Solve[% /. C[1] -> coef, coef] // Flatten) /. coef -> C[1]
scx = sn /. # & /@ sc1
```

A sample plot, for two of the four `n = 3` solutions, is

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate[scx[[3 ;; 4]] /. n -> 3], {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> 
    {t, x}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

A corresponding `NDSolve` solution is

```
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ic11, ic12, ic21, ic22}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, L}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -6.5 - 5.5 I, y'[0] == -5/3 I}}];
ReImPlot[First[sn], {t, 0, L}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, ReImStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Can we set "Finite Difference Method"  for NDSolve? e.g. for 4th order 1D problems?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Finite Difference is the default method for most ODEs.  Finite Element also can be used in some situations, but probably not for the ODE system here.

Comment: if FD is the default method in MMA, why does NDsolve not easy solve 4th order PDEs?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  My comment above is for ODEs.  PDEs are a different issue.

Comment: can NDsolve solve 4th (6th) order ODE systems?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Yes.  If you are having difficulty doing so, post a new questions with the details of the code you have tried.

Comment: thanks!!! I have tried to solve a 4th order odes systems, however, it takes too long time in MMA, until now no solution...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Initial value problems are solvable with little difficulty, unless they are stiff.  Boundary value problems sometimes take a bit of thought.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Additional, oscillatory solutions found.

Comment: is it the best way that we solve the equation "ode2" at the end of the calculation?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  It is a good way, but I am considering other ways and hope to have something in a day or two.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  I have found an alternative approach, which I hope to publish this weekend.  However, for most purposed I would recommend the method at the end of the answer above.