# Stiff System of ODEs: NDSolve Convergence Issues

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, modeling, boundary-conditions

I have tried to use NDSolve for solving ***4th*** order **coupled ODEs problems** (see the attached codes). The MMA solver fails to solve this problem.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
L = 10;
ode1 = y''[t] - 0.01 y''''[t] == 0;
ic11 = y[0] == 0;
ic12 = y''[0] == 0;
ic13 = y'[L] == 0;
ic14 = x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 1/20;
ode2 = -10 (4.7169 (1.12 - x[t]) + 0.2120 x''[t]) + 
    424000 x[t] (y'[t]^2 + 0.010 y''[t]^2) == 0;
ic21 = x'[0] == 0;
ic22 = x'[L] == 0;
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ic11, ic12, ic13, ic14, ic21, 
    ic22}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 1}}];
```

Note that **the initial value of x must equal 1.12**.

How can I set the "Shooting" method in MMA for solving Stiff System of ODEs?
Namely, how to define the initial values for the "Shooting" method in MMA.

**Update Version 01_2020.**

Now we are trying to verify the method proposed by **@bbgodfrey**

Such test procedure looks like that:

*ic4 has changed to*

> ic14 = x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 0;

**The input file:**

```
L = 10;
ode1 = y''[t] - 0.01 y''''[t] == 0;
ic11 = y[0] == 0;
ic12 = y''[0] == 0;
ic13 = y'[L] == 0;
ic14 = x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 0;
ode2 = -10 (4.7169 (1.12 - x[t]) + 0.2120 x''[t]) + 
    424000 x[t] (y'[t]^2 + 0.010 y''[t]^2) == 0;
ic21 = x'[0] == 0;
ic22 = x'[L] == 0;
sy = (DSolve[{ode1, ic11, ic12, ic13}, y, t] // Flatten) /. 
  C[1] -> c Exp[-100]
ode2x = Simplify[ode2 /. sy];

ic14x = Collect[ic14 /. sy, x[10], Simplify];
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode2x /. c -> c[t], ic14x /. c -> c[L], ic21, ic22,
      c'[t] == 0}, {x[t], c[10]}, t, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -1/2, c[0] == I/8}}] // 
   Flatten;
sn // Last
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@First@sn, {t, 0, L}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, x}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Last[y /. sy /. c -> Last[sn]], {t, 0, L}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, y}, 
 LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

**the output:** should be **y ==0 and x = const 1.12 for ic4 (new one)**:

> ic14 = x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 0;

**The simulated results:**

[image]

Obviously, ***x is not const, oscillation can be observed.***

Comment: I recommend that you solve for `y` , using any boundary conditions that depend on `y` only, and then insert that result into the ODE for `x`.  Also, be sure to replace any  `C[_]` constants in the expression for `y` by constants without indices before that substitution.

Comment: I added a monitor: `Print[Dynamic@{foo, Clock[Infinity]}]; sn = NDSolveValue[..., StepMonitor :> (foo = t)]`.  It shows that shooting for the correct initial conditions takes a long time. You say the problem is stiffness — maybe you know that theoretically — but if you could give better starting initial conditions, you might solve it. [Added: @bbgodfrey's idea seems better; didn't see it.]

Comment: @bbgodfrey in the second step (your method): Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Requiring that `x[0] == 1` as a boundary condition would overspecify this ode system.  Note, however, that `"StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == 1}` does not guarantee that the solution for `x` is equal to `1` at `t = 0`.

Answer (score 5):

This system is similar in some respects to [question 228267](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228301/1063), but much more challenging.  It can be solved as follows.  First, as a good practice, `Rationalize` all equations in the question.  Then, solve for `y`, which can be done symbolically.

```
sy = (DSolve[{ode1, ic11, ic12, ic13}, y, t] // Flatten) /. C[1] -> c Exp[-100]
(* {y -> Function[{t}, 1/100 E^(-100 - 10 t)(-((E^100 c)/E^100) + (E^(100 + 20 t) c)/E^100
    - (10 E^(10 t) t c)/E^100 - (10 E^(200 + 10 t) t c)/E^100)]} *)
```

Because `c` is an arbitrary constant, it can be renormalized as desired, here to assure that `c` is of order unity in magnitude.  Applying this result to `ode2` and `ic14` yields

```
ode2x = Simplify[ode2 /. sy]
(* (47169 x[t])/1000 + 4240 E^(-20 (20 + t)) (2 E^200 + E^(20 t) + 2 E^(40 (5 + t)) - 
   2 E^(10 (10 + t)) + 2 E^(20 (10 + t)) - 2 E^(30 (10 + t)) + E^(20 (20 + t)) 
   - 2 E^(10 (30 + t)) - 2 E^(100 + 30 t)) c[t]^2 x[t] == 330183/6250 + (53 x''[t])/25 *)
ic14x = Collect[ic14 /. sy, x[10], Simplify]
(* -(((1 + E^200) c x[10]^2)/(10 E^200)) == 1/20 *)
```

Use the procedure described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691) to solve for `x` and `c`.

```
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode2x /.c -> c[t], ic14x /. c -> c[L], ic21, ic22, c'[t] == 0}, 
    {x[t], c[10]}, t, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -1/2, c[0] == I/8}}] // Flatten;
sn//Last
(* 0.000769293 + 0.12592 I *)
```

which is `c`.

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@First@sn, {t, 0, L}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@Last[y /. sy /. c -> Last[sn]], {t, 0, L}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

[image]

**Addendum: Four families of solutions**

Because two of the three conditions, `{ic14x, ic21, ic22}` are evaluated at `x = L` and only one at `x = 0`, integrating from `L` to `0` is both faster and more robust that integrating from `0` to `L`.  This permits the rapid computation of four distinct eigenfunction-like families of solutions.  To begin, solve `ic14x` for `x[L]` in terms of `c[L]`.

```
sxL = (Solve[ic14x, x[L]] // Flatten) /. Rule -> Equal
(* {x[10] == -((I E^100)/(Sqrt[2 + 2 E^200] Sqrt[c[10]])), 
    x[10] == (I E^100)/(Sqrt[2 + 2 E^200] Sqrt[c[10]])} *)
```

Now, find and plot the first twelve solutions for `sxL//First` and `Im[c] > 0`.

```
Sort[Union[Flatten@Table[Quiet@Check[
    NDSolveValue[{ode2x, sxL // First, ic21, ic22, c'[t] == 0}, {c[L]}, t, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {c[L] == n I}}] // Flatten, 
    Nothing], {n, .105, .135, .0005}], 
    SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-4 &)], Im[#1] < Im[#2] &];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[(s = 
    NDSolveValue[{ode2x, sxL // First, ic21, ic22, c'[t] == 0}, {x[t], c[L]}, t, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {c[L] == #}}];
    Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@First@s, {t, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> Last@s]) & /@ %, 
    UpTo[3]], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The identical code with `sxL // First` replaced by `sxL // Last` yields

[image]

The remaining two sets are obtained as above but with the "StartingInitialConditions" `c[L] == n I` replaced by `c[L] == -n I`.

[image]

[image]

I do not believe that there are other solution families.

**Second Addendum: Accuracy Demonstration**

To illustrate the accuracy of the computations above, first apply `sy`, to `{ode1, ic11, ic12, ic13}`

```
Simplify[{ode1, ic11, ic12, ic13} /. sy]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

A typical evaluation of `x`, obtained using the procedure introduce in the preceding addendum,

```
sn = NDSolveValue[{ode2x, sxL // First, ic21, ic22, c'[t] == 0}, {x, c[L]}, t, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {c[L] == 126 10^-3 I}}, InterpolationOrder -> All]
     // Flatten]
```

which yields, when plotted, the first plot in the answer.  Now, compute the corresponding numerical error,

```
(Subtract @@ ode2x) /. x -> First[sn] /. c[t] -> Last[sn];
Plot[Norm@%%, {t, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {0, 10^-5}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, err}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The largest error, `0.00156` at `t = L`, is a bit large but nonetheless satisfactory.  (Reducing the maximum error by using a larger `WorkingPrecision` makes no visible difference to a plot of the solution.)  Application of `sn` to the remaining boundary conditions shows that they too are well satisfied.

```
(Subtract @@ First[sxL]) /. x -> First[sn] /. c[10] -> Last[sn]
(* -6.66134*10^-16 - 2.22045*10^-16 I *)
(Subtract @@ ic21) /. x -> First[sn] /. c[0] -> Last[sn]
(* 3.49637*10^-7 + 1.73382*10^-8 I *)
(Subtract @@ ic22) /. x -> First[sn] /. c[10] -> Last[sn]
(* 0. + 0. I *)
```

Comment: Thanks ! As mentioned, the initial value of x needs to equal one.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  You cannot force `x[0] == 1` unless you use it as a boundary condition, which you have not done.

Comment: to check the results, firstly, we can set ic14:    x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 0.; And the correct results must be that:  x = 1 and y = 0 for t =[0 10], however, the proposed method does not provid this result.

Comment: we just want to check your method in MMA, then we use ic14: x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 0.01*y'''[L]) == 0. if we use this new bc, then y must be zero, Next step, if y equals 0,  x will never be changed in ode2, which means the resulting x must equal the initial value x_0.

Comment: As I mentioned, for the test job (a  simple test procedure), we use the new ic4: x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 10^-2*y'''[L]) == 0, not old one 1/20. The verify process is that use this new bc, then y must be zero, Next step, if y equals 0, x will never be changed in ode2, which means the resulting x must equal the initial value x_0

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Setting `y = 0` changes the problem profoundly, resulting in `x = 1.12`.  However, I do not see what is being accomplished.  It in no way validates or invalidates my answer.

Comment: I have added the update in the post, it shows the oscillation output for the new ic4: x[L]*x[L]*(y'[L] - 10^-2*y'''[L]) == 0, x = 1.12 along t= [0 10] axis is not observed.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Up to a multiplicative constant, ic14x is `c[L] x[[L]^2 == 0`, which is satisfied by either `c[L] = 0` or x[L]^2 = 0`.  `NDSolve` chose the latter, giving a result with `x[L]^2 = 10^-7`, satisfying the `AccuracyGoal`.  For `WorkingPrecision -> 30`, `x[L]` decreases to about `5*10^-14`.  Because `ic14x` puts no constraint on `c` in this case, it can have any value, for instance `I/8`, which is what your computation produced.  For `"StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == -1/2, c[0] == 0}}` instead, `NDSolve` gives `y = 0` and `x = 1.12`.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Simply stated, my answer approach only works for the right side of `ic14x` not equal to zero.  If you do not believe my answer, the way to test it is to substitute it into the ODEs and ICs.

Comment: We are just testing this method with different benchmark tests, anyhow, numerical tests are necessary.

Comment: for such coupled 4th order ODEs can we find an analytical solution in MMA?

Comment: Cite "my answer approach only works for the right side of ic14x not equal to zero. "  if the right side equals 2, 20 or 200 it also not works, namely no FindRoots.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM  Sorry to be slow to respond.  I was able to obtain solutions for `1/20` replaced by `200`.  I imagine that the computation would fail for a sufficiently large coefficient, however.